# Can't seem to add new line when using three state workflow sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am having trouble when trying to send email using three-state workflow. I can't seem to add a new line in the message body even when I've added a new line.

When the workflow is initiated, I've put up an email message that is sent to assigned users.

[image: Email Message]

I've tried multiple things: /n, /n/r, , but the email the user recieve is always without a new line

[image: Email]

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: which workflow version you are working with? with SP 2013 workflow this is working for me without any tag

Comment: working with SP 2010 Workflow as well but line spacing is a bit less. Try opening email in outlook web client, seem to be issue with email client than SP workflow

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider I'm working with Sharepoint online. And yes it seems to be the issue with outlook client.